# Java Enhanced Caesar Cipher: Issue to understand behavior of for loop

Tags: java

This is a Caesar cipher code and while debugging i found this loop running more than the mod's value. I wanted the output to be `1,2,3,4 fklm` then stop. the loop in question is:

```
for(int k=1;k<=mod;k++).
```

The String used in the method is `"abcd"`.

[Output image included below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z63cc.png)

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText)
{
    plainText=plainText.toLowerCase();
    String text="";
    for(int i=0;i<plainText.length();i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
         int letterPosition=ALPHABET.indexOf(plainText.charAt(i));
         int shiftValue=(key+letterPosition)%26;
         char encrypted=ALPHABET.charAt(shiftValue);
         text+=encrypted;
        }
        else if(i>0)
        {
            int letterPosition=ALPHABET.indexOf(plainText.charAt(i));
                for(int k=1;k<=mod;k++)
                {
                     modShiftKey=(key+k);
                     System.out.println(k);
                }
            int shiftValue=(modShiftKey+letterPosition)%26;
            char encrypted=ALPHABET.charAt(shiftValue);
            text+=encrypted;
        }
    }
    return text;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like that the inner `for` loop can be completely replaced with just the line:

```
modShiftKey=(key+mod);
```

Then a new for loop can be added prior to the first for loop:

```
String text = "";
for (int k = 1; k <= mod; k++) {
    System.out.print("" + k + (k == mod ? " " : ","));
}
```

(assuming you're not wanting to store 1, 2, 3, 4 in the `text` variable, of course)